# Handle multiple occurrences of value conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query which is mapping rows with a particular key to an ID.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Note, Importdate, Group
FROM 
    SAP_OPListen2015 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         Rechnnr, K, Aufttext, Betrag 
     FROM 
         SAP_OPListen2015 
     WHERE 
          ID = 75790) AS sq_Temp ON SAP_OPListen2015.Rechnnr = sq_Temp.Rechnnr 
                                 AND SAP_OPListen2015.K = sq_Temp.K 
                                 AND SAP_OPListen2015.Aufttext = sq_Temp.Aufttext 
                                 AND sq_Temp.Betrag = SAP_OPListen2015.Betrag 
ORDER BY 
    Importdate
```

Execution is returning the following rows:

```
ID      NOTE    IMPORTDATE              GROUP
----------------------------------------------
75790   NULL    2016-05-30 00:00:00.000 NULL
76357   NULL    2016-05-30 00:00:00.000 G
74186   NULL    2016-04-30 00:00:00.000 E
72688   NULL    2016-03-30 00:00:00.000 NULL
71019   NULL    2015-11-30 00:00:00.000 NULL
69481   NULL    2015-10-31 00:00:00.000 NULL
68173   NULL    2015-09-30 00:00:00.000 NULL
67142   NULL    2015-05-31 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

You see that the importdate (2016-05-30) is occurring twice. I want that if the same date is occurring twice, then it should only return the row where "Group" is equal 'G'.

Someone know how to do this? I tried nearly everything but I realize that I lack some syntax knowledge of SQL.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The result I want to see here is:

```
ID      NOTE    IMPORTDATE              GROUP
----------------------------------------------
76357   NULL    2016-05-30 00:00:00.000 G
74186   NULL    2016-04-30 00:00:00.000 E
72688   NULL    2016-03-30 00:00:00.000 NULL
71019   NULL    2015-11-30 00:00:00.000 NULL
69481   NULL    2015-10-31 00:00:00.000 NULL
68173   NULL    2015-09-30 00:00:00.000 NULL
67142   NULL    2015-05-31 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a variation of a `top-n-per-group` query.

Here is one way to do it using `ROW_NUMBER()`. This function will assign a number for each row. Its `PARTITION BY Importdate` clause will restart row numbers from 1 for each date. Its `ORDER BY` clause would put row with `[Group] = 'G'` at the top of the partition and these rows would have `rn = 1`.

If you have two or more rows with the same `Importdate` and `[Group] = 'G'`, it is not defined which row will be picked. You can add more columns to the `ORDER BY` clause (such as `ID`) to define which row to pick.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, Note, Importdate, Group
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Importdate 
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Group] = 'G' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS rn
    FROM 
        SAP_OPListen2015 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                Rechnnr, K, Aufttext, Betrag 
            FROM 
                SAP_OPListen2015 
            WHERE 
                ID = 75790
        ) AS sq_Temp 
            ON SAP_OPListen2015.Rechnnr = sq_Temp.Rechnnr 
            AND SAP_OPListen2015.K = sq_Temp.K 
            AND SAP_OPListen2015.Aufttext = sq_Temp.Aufttext 
            AND sq_Temp.Betrag = SAP_OPListen2015.Betrag 
)
SELECT
    ID, Note, Importdate, Group
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY 
    Importdate
;
```